# How to change path of ckeditor image upload

Tags: laravel, ftp, ckeditor, laravel-filesystem

I have laravel application and using ckeditor and laravel file manager to upload images and files. This store images in public/photos folder. I want to change folder where images are stored. I have set ftp disk in laravel filesystem (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem).

So I want to store all images uploaded from ckeditor to new server which is define by ftp disk in config/filesystem.php.

Please help me out!

Comment: where did you defined that `public/photos` path for image storing?

Answer (score 1):

In app/config/lfm.php find:
'base_directory' => 'public'

Replace public with your storage path, for example
'base_directory' => 'storage/app/media'

This works for local, I think it would work for remote work too.